# Time Machine: Is it possible to exclude 5000+ files via TMUTIL?

Tags: macos, terminal, backup

Is there a limit to the number of files which can be excluded in TimeMachine?

I have 5000+ photos on an external drive along with their associated sidecar files.  The photos are large and never change (I back them up separately) but I need to backup the sidecar files.  The photos and sidecar files need to be located in the same directory

So, I thought I would just exclude the photos using TMUTIL.  I thought I could do it with one command for the whole directory structure.  That didn't work.  So I did it by year which worked at first but I seem to be reaching a limit (Around 1315) and when I try to  exclude just a few, i get the error:
Insufficient privileges to change exclusion setting.
(Although I don;t think it's anything to do with privileges).

Does anyone have any advice please…?

Many thanks, Karen

Comment: I just took a cursory review of the man page for TMUTIL and the _addexclusion_ verb doesn't show supporting exclusion by file type per se however it would be interesting to see the actual command line you executed.  Anyway it looks like you're hitting a limit of some sort, for what reason I can't say, however I'd probably take a different approach by excluding the primary parent folder and then use a different mechanism to backup the "sidecar files".

Comment: Continuation of previous Comment...  As an example the target files to be backed up could be scripted to mirror the hierarchical structure just containing the "sidecar files" and then that location be backed up or an archive containing the "sidecar files" be created to a location that would naturally be backed up by Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

If there are hard limits, sorry, I don't know what they are however I have many exclusions set for **Time Machine** and one in particular has 294,691 files in it.  So instead of doing it folder by folder try setting the exclusion from **Options...** in **Time Machine** under **System Preferences**.

Plug in the external drive and then either drag and drop the parent folder containing the files you want to exclude or the drive icon into the **Exclude these items from backups:** list area or use the [+][-] buttons.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your reply… Sorry, I should have said, i was doing this via TMUTIL as I needed to exclude a specific file type so couldn't exclude the directory in the Time Machine GUI.